# Error while using python file generated from SWIG (generated from C++)

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, swig

I have a .cpp (called trial.cpp) file as follows:

> ```
>    #include "trial.hpp"
>    int main()
>    {
>         cout << "hello";
>        return 0;
>    }
> ```

My header file (trial.hpp) is:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> ```

I have a .i file (trial.i) as follows:

> ```
> %module trial
> %{
> #include "trial.hpp"
> %}
>
> %include trial.hpp
> ```

I have used SWIG in the following manner in cmd to generate .pyd, .py, .o and .cxx files:

> swig -c++ -python trial.i
>
> g++ -c trial_wrap.cxx -I C:\Users.....Python\Python37\include
>
> g++ -shared trial_wrap.o -o _trial.pyd -L
>   C:\Users.....\Python\Python37\libs -l
>   python37

The files are generated successfully

However when I open Python command prompt and run this:

> from trial import *
>
> main()

I get an error saying

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>
> NameError: name 'main' is not defined

How can I resolve this issue?

**Moreover, if I'm using another function name (say fn1()) instead of main(), I get the following error in the third command:**

> **g++ -shared trial_wrap.o -o _trial.pyd -L**
>   **C:\Users.....\Python\Python37\libs -l python37**

The error is:

> **undefined reference to fn1()**

I'd like to use fn1() instead of main()

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I don't know anything about swig, but `main` is special in C++. Try using another function name and declare it in the header (and remove that `using namespace std;`, it will cause more harm than the few saved keystrokes are worth)

Comment: When I tried using another function name (lets call it fn1()) and provided the definition in the header, I get an error saying 'undefined reference to fn1() while trying to run the third statement in SWIG mentioned in the question'

Comment: Your header file doesn't declare the function you're looking to wrap, so it won't be wrapped.

Comment: No that isn't true. "%include trial.hpp" tells SWIG to wrap all available functions

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

Used these three statements instead:

> swig -c++ -python trial.i
>
> g++ -c trial_wrap.cxx trial.cpp -I C:\Users\ngoyal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include
>
> g++ -shared -o _trial.pyd trial.o trial_wrap.o -L C:\Users\ngoyal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\libs -l python37

Also had to change main() to a non reserved function name and gave the function definition in the header file.